# GeoServer call WPS process and get ID back

Tags: geoserver, wps

I want to call a WPS process from inside my app. I want to get the ID back to be able send a dismiss command and abort the calculation. I achieve this by adding

```
<wps:ResponseDocument storeExecuteResponse="false" status="true">
</wps:ResponseDocument>
```

into the xml I am posting. The problem here is that I only get the ID together with the result back. Wich is of course at the end of the WPS execution. In order to terminate it I need the ID prior to the start of the execution and than wait fot the result to be transmitted in a second call?

How can I get the ID and later on the result in the same connection?

Edit: even though I don't think it will help here is the code I use to call the WPS. It is written in AutoIt v3 (kind of basic).

```
Global $oHTTP = ObjCreate("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
$oHTTP.Open("POST", $geoserverURL, False)
$oHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8")
$oHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Length",StringLen($xml))
$oHTTP.send($xml)
$oReceived = $oHTTP.ResponseText
```

The xml I post is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>gs:BufferFeatureCollectionM</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:testRaster="testRaster">
            <wfs:Query typeName="testRaster:myTest"/>
          </wfs:GetFeature>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>distance</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>200</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
<wps:ResponseDocument storeExecuteResponse="false" status="true"> 
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/json">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
</wps:ResponseDocument> 
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

I get the result together with the ID when the process has finished. If I would get some kind of response earlier I would Split this string out of the surroundings.

Comment: can you edit the question to add the request you are making and the code you use to get the id

Comment: I added the part where I call the WPS. The total script would be a bit out of scope (~ 500 lines)